# Is it possible to use referenced model with different inports data types?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to build a model with many same blocks, which need to have different inports data types. Is it possible to make it with referenced models (no subsystems/library blocks) ?

I've already did it with subsystems, but copying objects with changing some parameters manually looks depressing. I put repeatable code in a separate model, created arguments with which I want to change the data types of the output ports.

I got a behavior I didn't expect - the arguments only affected the values of the blocks of constants, but the port types remained the same as in the default values of the arguments.

UPD. All these models are used in HDL code generation.

Comment: Could you please clarify a few points: What Matlab version are you using? Is there a reason you cannot set input/output size and data type as inheritable and still use library blocks?

Comment: @Mefitico, Matlab R2017a.
I use the WordLenght operator in Matlab function block to construct a persistent variable of a certain size:
`y_tmp = fi(0, 0, in.WordLength, 0, fimath('OverflowAction', 'wrap'))`
where `in` is the fixed-size input.
All this is necessary to generate hdl code.

Comment: Designing a model to generate HLD code is vastly different than doing so for running Simulink. Please mention this kind of thing in your question! Then, I think you can use a parameter that has the value of in.WordLength, and add this parameter to a mask in the respective block.

Comment: @Mefitico, yes, I can use a parameter as you said, but it behaves not as I expect. Assume two models: top and reference (which is parametrized). Parametrized model have simple inport and outport with data type inheritance; ports are connected to Matlab function block with simple math and persistent value. When I set persistent value or input via parameter - OK, this works. But when I try to set parameter value from top model and compile - reference model types remains as default parameter.